# Importar banco WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Boa tarde, existe uma forma de importar um banco de dados de um site
que não foi feito em WordPress para um novo site feito em WordPress?

Comment: Exite, refatorar o banco adaptando as tabelas e colunas para as do wordpress, mas não é nada simples, já que os bancos de dados podem ser criados de formas muito ditintas.

Answer (score 1):

É possivel mas não diretamente. Você vai precisar escrever um ou mais scripts que convertam as informações do banco antigo para o formato do banco novo.

Uma ferramenta que ajuda muito nesse processo é [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/), que permite que você escreva os scripts em PHP mesmo, usando os métodos nativos do WordPress, e execute na linha de comando, evitando timeouts e problemas de memória comuns no navegador. O processo normalmente é o seguinte:

1. Planeje em detalhes a estrutura do novo banco, onde vai cada informação existente. Nesse passo é comum inclusive decidir quais infos vão ser importadas e quais não vão.
2. Estude o banco original e separe os dados em grandes grupos de acordo com o que eles vão ser no novo site. É comum anotar onde ficam no banco original as informações que vao ser transformadas em **taxonomias**, **autores**, **post types**, **meta values** e **options**.
3. Implemente os códigos necessários pra formar a estrutura completa do novo site, pra que você já tenha uma base pronta para testar quando terminar a importação. Esse passo é muito importante ser feito antes da importação porque durante o desenvolvimento você vai ver detalhes que são difíceis de perceber só de olhar pro banco, por exemplo, se uma determinada informação te serve melhor como taxonomia ou como meta-value, de acordo com como ela vai ser usada. Uma vez pronta a nova estrutura, com conteúdos de teste, você sabe que a estrutura te atende então é so mandar bala.
4. Escreva os scripts CLI que vão ler do banco original e salvar no novo banco. Nesse ponto você usa o WP-CLI pra fazer a importação usando já os métodos originais do WP, de forma que os dados incidentais (tipo meta-dados de imagens, ou post-date-gmt, por exemplo) sejam gerados automaticamente e você não precise fazer na mão.
5. Importe as informações nessa ordem: **autores (users) > taxonomias > mídia > posts + meta > configurações + options**. Você precisa das taxonomias no lugar pra anexar os posts quando eles entrarem. E precisa das imagens também, pra que os posts possam ler delas.

Acho que o básico é esse. Dai você vai adaptar os passos pro seu projeto.